# How to extract content from FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, http

I have a `FormUrlEncodedContent` how can i extract data from it

```
 public void sample(FormUrlEncodedContent request, string url)
                {
                Console.Writeline(url);
                Console.Writeline(request);
                }
```

This returns `System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) shows a variety of operations available on that object.  For example, if you just want to read it as a string, you can use `ReadAsStringAsync`:

```
public async Task sample(FormUrlEncodedContent request, string url)
{
    Console.Writeline(url);
    Console.Writeline(await request.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```